# how to make functions executes in order

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm making a project using angular and firebase, and I'm facing problem how to make a function to work synchronously .
So my contrat.ts looks like this:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ContratService } from './contrat.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray} from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contrat',
  templateUrl: './contrat.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contrat.component.css']
}) 
export class ContratComponent implements OnInit {
  today: number = Date.now();

  contrat: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder ,private contratService: ContratService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.contrat=this.fb.group({
      id_Contrat : [''],
      Montant : [''],
      date : [''],
      id_Client : [''],
      id_Freelancer : [''],
      tache : this.fb.array([this.creatTache()])
    })
this.contrat.get('date').setValue(this.today);
  }


creatTache():FormGroup{
  return this.fb.group({
           tacheName: [''],
           paiement:[''],
           delai:['']
  })
}
public get tache(){
  return this.contrat.controls['tache'] as FormArray;
}
addTache(){
this.tache.push(this.creatTache());
}
removeTache(i:number){
  this.tache.removeAt(i);
}
try1(){
  let m=0;
  for(let t of this.contrat.get('tache').value){
    m= +m + +t.paiement;
   }

  this.contrat.get('Montant').setValue(m);
}

 try2(u){
  this.contratService.addContrat(u);
}
 onSubmit(i){
this.try1();
this.try2(i);

}

}
```

in the method try1() I was trying to setValue the 'Montant'
and in the method try2() I was trying to send the data to firebase

the problem is that try2() executes before try1()

Comment: try `console.trace` in each try method they shoul start from onSubmit if they dont that is the reason why they are not sync

Comment: in your contratService is addContrat(u) async?

Comment: yup it is async

Answer (score 1):

I simply added an attribute in html

```html
 <input formControlName="paiement" (input)="try1()" type="text">
```

I called the method try1() by the event (input) so the value of "Montant" will change every time the user touch the input "Paiement".

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
this.contrat.patchValue({Montant: m});
```

instead of `setValue`

Answer (score -1):

Everything in JavaScript is asynchronous. 
Meaning that if a line of code is waiting for  something (Ex a back-end request) then it proceeds to the next line of code without stalling.

What you can do is use prommise.

```
    try1(){
      return new promise of((return) => {
      let m=0;
      for(let t of this.contrat.get('tache').value){
        m= +m + +t.paiement;
       }

      this.contrat.get('Montant').setValue(m);
      return();
     });
    }

     try2(u){
      this.contratService.addContrat(u);
    }
     onSubmit(i){
    this.try1().then(()=> {
    this.try2(i);
    });
   }
```

Comment: sorry but it showed alot of errors I'm sorry but I don't know much about  the promises .thank you tho